# PHP regular expression matching

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Given the input string "*othertext ?.abc.de.fgh.i moretext*" and the pattern **'/\?(\.[a-zA-Z]*)*/'** I'm trying to use function `preg_match_all` to get an array of matches with the elements *.abc*, *.de*, *.fgh*, and *.i* but only *?.abc.de.fgh.i* and *.i* are matched. ([The test](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/vFY))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make use of the `\G` anchor

```
(?:\?|\G(?!^))\K\.[a-zA-Z]+
```

In parts:

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\?` Match `?`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert position at the end of previous match, not at the start
- `)` Close group
- `\K\.[a-zA-Z]+` Forget what is currently matched, and match the `.` and 1+ chars a-zA-Z

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EBtfhG/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/QKZm4)

```
$re = '/(?:\?|\G(?!^))\K\.[a-zA-Z]+/';
$str = 'othertext ?.abc.de.fgh.i moretext';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) ".abc"
  [1]=>
  string(3) ".de"
  [2]=>
  string(4) ".fgh"
  [3]=>
  string(2) ".i"
}
```

Comment: Why `(?!^)` is needed?

Comment: @Oleg that is because the `\G` matches at 2 positions. At the start of the string or at the position of the previous match. See this page for more information https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#G